# Easy way to build a webfont based off of .png files

Tags: css, icons, webfonts

Designer at our company has provided me an icon set as a series of .png files (1x and 2x per icon) that I'd really like to switch over to be a webfont instead.

Is there a best practice for doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

If your png's are of good quality you can open them in Adobe Illustrator.

Click on an image. On the top bar, a button 'Image Trace' ('Bildnachzeichner' in german) appears. Click on small arrow next to 'Image Trace' box for drop down menu. 
Select ‘High Fidelity Photo’ to begin image trace, if the result doesn't fit try other options from the drowndown menu.

Next you will see an 'Expand'-Button at the top ('Umwandeln' in german).
Click it. Vercotr paths and fills are created.
You can adjust them if you need and save it to a svg file.

Then import to icomoon.io ...

Answer (score 0):

I've used [icomoon.io](http://icomoon.io/#app-features) in the past. I think with only .png files though you can only make an image sprite. You'll need the files in .svg format to make an icon font.

Answer (score -2):

DON'T DO IT.

Use a [sprite sheet](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/11/css-sprites-revisited/) instead.